# How to pass if statement with $request in parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am in a real pickle here. I have a webpage that displays people's names in a table. In this table there is a select form where I indicate whether they are a "good noodle". In the database the good noodle variable is a boolean. I will put my code below. My problem is that I cannot get it to update whatever is selected by me in the good noodle option to the record of the re-existing brother.

When I try to print out and see what the value is, it works just fine. But for whatever reason it will not update the record.

My controller:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $brothers = Brother::all();

    foreach ($brothers as $b){
        $b->GoodNoodle = $request['goodNoodle'];
        $b->save();

        //Failed attempt #1
        //if ($request['goodNoodle'] == "No"){
            //$b->GoodNoodle = "0";
            //$b->save();
            //}
        //else{
            //$b->GoodNoodle = "1";
            //$b->save();
            //}

        //Failed Attempt #2 ive also tried every variation of this
        //if($b['goodNoodle'] != $request['goodNoodle']){
          //$b->GoodNoodle = $request->goodNoodle;
          //$b->save();
        //}
    }

}
```

My blade.php:

```
<form method="Post" action="{{route('update_brother')}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody class="text-center">
                <tr>
                    <th>Good Noodle</th>
                    <th>Brother Name</th>
                    <th>Brother Class</th>
                    <th>Zeta Number</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach($brothers as $b)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="goodNoodle">
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                <option value="0"{{!$b["goodNoodle"]? "selected": ""}}>No</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$b->fName.' '.$b->lName}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$b->zetaClass}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="zetaNum">{{$b->zetaNum}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Here are some clues. If I do this:

```
$value = $request->GoodNoodle; //with $value being equal to 1

if $b['goodNoodle'] = $value{
   $b->goodNoodle = "0"
}
```

Then it will change all my records to 0. But if I do

```
$value = $request->GoodNoodle; //with $value being equal to 1

if $b['goodNoodle'] = $value{
   $b->goodNoodle = $value
}
```

it will not do anything. Please help.

Comment: first if you want to compare 2 values in PHP, you shoud say if (a == b) and not one equal like you made...

Comment: Try this  $b->goodNoodle = $request->get('goodNoodle');
        $b->save();

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using ternary operator too.

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="goodNoodle">
    <option value="0" {{ $b->goodNoodle == '0' ? 'selected' : '' }}>No</option>
    <option value="1" {{ $b->goodNoodle == '1' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Yes</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare value from DB and from request do this:

```
if ($b['goodNoodle'] == $request->goodNoodle)
```

Instead of:

```
if($b['goodNoodle'] = $request->goodNoodle])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your select box as below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="goodNoodle">
 <option value="0" @if($b->goodNoodle == '0') selected @endif>No</option>
 <option value="1" @if($b->goodNoodle == '1') selected @endif>Yes</option>
</select>
```